# How to get usage details of AWS EBS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, aws-ebs

My team got billing for [AWS EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) and we have no idea what is it about.

Going to our console and try to open EBS section though we failed to get one as the snapshots below.

So my question is how to get breakdown details on AWS EBS usage billing?

[image]

p.s.

The EBS usage cost is viewed under EC2 section in billing tab in the management console[image]

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: Have you try a search on similar questions about AWS pricing? I see there are others you will also need to vote to close too @MarkB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBS is under EC2 in the AWS Management Console. If you look at the `size of your volumes`, the `type of volumes` and also the `size of your snapshots` that should help identify the cost.

E.g. faster volumes types, provisioned IOPS, large volumes/snapshots are more expensive.

You can put this information into the `AWS Simple Montly Calculator` to work out the cost https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

You can also look at the usage in CloudWatch, however it's under EBS there and shows per volume statistics.

Comment: And how may I know how much each volume of each EC2 instance cost?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to work that out from the size and type of each volume and the pricing page or count them all and use the AWS Simple Monthly Calculator https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html. Or you could also use a service like CloudCheckr to do it for you, or use the AWS monthly billing reports to work it out retrospectively http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html

Comment: Oh I'll try those and back to you when it  gets settled

Comment: The AWS Calculator solves me the problem. Please update your answer to get it accepted. Thank you! @NHol

Answer (score 1):

For AWS billing you can use cost explorer for generating handsome reports.

***Billing Break-Down:***

In aws they have grouped multiple offerings under one service. **For ex: EBS, ELB, EIP all grouped under EC2.**

Same when they provide billing breakdown they provide it on service basis then region basis and then offering.

If you want better breakdown best way is to use **cost tags** and **cost explorer**.

> Like in your case you can give your `service_tag = ebs` and `application_tag = app1`.
>
> Then by using cost explorer :  `filter_by = app_tag and region and etc.` and `group_by = service_tag`. By performing multiple combinations you can get a clear view of your cost and usage.

Comment: I'm looking for how to understand/breakdown the EBS billing charged - not asking for what it is. Thanks any way!

Comment: for this type of breakdown best way is to use tag based breakdown.